# Usercontrol click event calling new usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making one student registration system in WPF, i have one very odd query regarding it that i have one window inside which there are two stackpanels and in both the stack panels usercontrol are added dynamically.
Eg.Usercontrol 1 is added to Stackpanel1 for Window now these usercontrol-1 are generated dynamically lets say they are student names , now when i click one of the student names (usercontrol -1) it should get all the details of that particular student and call new usercontrol-2 and add as a child to stackpanel-2 in the window.

I am able to handle the click event for usercontrol-1 for each and every student and also get their information and pass those information to usercontrol-2 now what i need is how do i add that usercontrol -2 to stackpanel-2 of window from by writing code inside usercontrol-1 OR is there any other method for doing the same.

Please help me regarding this , i am really stucked up !!

Answer (score 0):

From your description I got that you are handling usercontrol-1 click inside it.
You can simply handle it's click event on the window level and place all code to add usercontrol-2 and initialize it there.